# Repeat function in Altium has no effect

Tags: altium

I used this function a lot of time, but I can't make it work anymore and I don't know if this is caused by an update.

How I declared it in my schematic:

[image]

How it does not have any effect:

[image]

Not relevant but these are my parameters:

[image]

Altium version 21.4.1 with original license.

Comment: Added a port, connected to nothing, and it works... seems to be a bug.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am having the same exact issue.

Answer (score 2):

the sheet symbol has to have a sheet entry that connects to a port somewhere in your schematic (i.e. VCC, GND, otherwise it doesn't work)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is exactly how I solved my problem by myself. Thanks again !